# non-rectangular shapes with css only?

Tags: css

I would like to have logos and text in rectangle shapes with the corners cut off. Do I need to use an SVG or can I do it in pure css?

[funky square shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CreN5.jpg)

I know its possible to make circles, triangles, stars etc in with only css but I am having trouble coding this particular shape up. Its a rectangle with the corners cut off.

Comment: you may use  pseudo element , box-shadow or background gradients and background-size in CSS

Answer (score 1):

example from my comment:

```css
div {
  /* demo purpose */
  margin:0.5em;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  display:inline-flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  /* end demo purpose, use your own display and sizes */
  background:
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, black 10px, black 40%, transparent 40% ),
    linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, black 10px, black 40%, transparent 40% ),
    linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 10px, black 10px, black 40%, transparent 40% ),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 10px, black 10px, black 40%, transparent 40% ),
    linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 30%, black 30%, black 70%, transparent 70% );
  color:lightgray;
  position:relative;
  font-size:40px;
  }
div:after {
  content:'';
  padding:5px;
  border:5px solid black;
  position:absolute;
}
/* Now fill up any corner from a class */
div.green:after {
  background:lime;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;  
}
div.red:after {
  background:tomato;
  top:0;
  right:0;  
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="green">
  <i class="fa  fa-mobile"></i>
</div>
<div class="red">
   <i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ::after and ::before

js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ymympva0/

```
.weird-shape:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 29px solid black;
    border-left: 29px solid white;
    border-right: 29px solid white;
    width: 42px;
    height: 0;
}

.weird-shape:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 29px solid black;
    border-left: 29px solid white;
    width: 42px;
    height: 0;
}
```

I have included 2 shapes. one is a colored version so you can see what it really does.

Answer (score -1):

you will have to add a div with a background the same as the color behind the image and have it cover the corners you want removed.